# Filtrar y mostar los datos en un listView o recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, listview

En mi actividad principal tengo un botón que al pulsarlo llama a una API-REST para consumir un `Json` con la predicción meteorológica de una ciudad para los próximos 5 días, esta predicción se guarda en un ArrayList de objetos Prediccion.

La predicción se muestra en un `ListView`, cada día de la predicción es un elemento de la lista y contiene: una fecha, un icono, una temperatura máxima y una mínima. Estos datos los extraigo,en mi ListAdapter, del ArrayList que he cargado con la llamada a la API-RES

Tengo que crear un filtro para  mostrar los días que el usuario quiera, por ejemplo **solo** los próximos 2 días ó 3 días .
Alguna idea de como filtrar, ya lo he intentado usando la librería JodaTime y comparando el campo fecha del ArrayList con la fecha actual pero no funciona.

```
public class Prediccion{
int tmpMax;
int tmpMin;
int diaMilliSecond;
}
```

Este es mi adaptador

```
    public class PrediccionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private List<Prediccion> mForescastList;

        @BindView(R.id.txt_forescast_day)
        TextView mForecastDate;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_temp_max)
        TextView mForecastTempMax;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_temp_min)
        TextView mForecastTempMin;
        @BindView(R.id.txt_sky_is)
        TextView mSkyConditions;
        @BindView(R.id.image_forecast_city_icon)
        ImageView mWeatherIcon;

        public PrediccionListAdapter(Context context, List<Prediccion> mList) {
            mContext = context;
            mForescastList = mList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mForescastList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mForescastList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = null;
            JodaTimeAndroid.init(mContext);
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
           //quiero filtrar y mostrar solo 3 días de los 5 que tengo
            Long endForescastDay = dateTime.plusDays(3).getMillis();

       //esto no funciona, sigue mostrando la lista entera
       if (mForescastList.get(position).getdiaMilliSecond < endForescastDay){
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
                        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_forescast_city, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            //Seteo todos los datos

         }
            return view;
        }
```

}

¿Sería mas eficiente (y fácil) en este caso implementar un recyclerview para filtrar?.
Gracias por anticipado

Comment: Mirate la libreria guava de google aqui un pequeño tutorial http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/001-filtering-collection-with-guava/

Comment: Aqui tienes una buena respuesta de como hacerlo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280722/java-efficient-arraylist-filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un ejemplo muy básico para filtrar una lista que cumpla una condición:

```
 int count = 0;
    ArrayList<String> _list;//ur arraylist with names
    for (String names : _list) {
        if (names.startsWith("R")) {
            count++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría el filtro antes de llamar a PrediccionListAdapter(Context context, List mList). Teniedo cargado todo en mList puedes programar un filtro que se encargue de seleccionar los datos que cumplan la condicion que quieras con la variable que quieras (tmpMax,tmpMin,diaMilliSecond). Luego como he dicho se lo pasas al adaptador.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta , creo que debe haber alguna otra forma usando la api de Android en el Adaptador en si mismo